# Excel hyperlink and vlookup

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vlookup

I need help getting a formula to work please. I have found multiple examples but cannot for the life of me get them to work. I need to have Excel take a value "name123" located in Worksheet "Maint" cell A2 and search Worksheet "Tracking" Column A for that exact match and have that name "name123" in the Maint worksheet a hyperlink that takes me to that exact match in the Tracking worksheet. The data is in column A on both worksheets. I am dealing with a very large dataset so searching for each value would be impractical.

This is what I have so far... Please tell me what is wrong with it!
=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(A2,Tracking!A:A,1,FALSE),A2)

Thank you guys in advance for your help!!!

Comment: The search range in Tracking worksheet is from A2:A33840

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in sheet Maint

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("ADDRESS",INDEX(Tracking!A:A,MATCH(A2,Tracking!A:A,0))),A2)
```

**Sheet Maint**

[image: Sheet Maint]

**Sheet Tracking**

[image: tracking sheet]

**Note:**

Reduce this `Tracking!A:A` to a shorter range if possible. Just the rows containing data in that sheet in column A which you want to match against.

**Demo:**

[image: Test run]

Comment: I get an error with this stating Excel cannot open the specified file.

Comment: Is your sheet spelt Tracking? Exactly same way with no white space? And in the same workbook?

Comment: I copied all the data to a NEW workbook and it worked. I don't know why it didn't with the other but thank you so much!!! You saved me a ton of time!

Comment: Actually, it works fine until I save the workbook then it says "can't open the specified file"

Comment: F it, it works fine saved as "Book3" so that's what we're going with! Thanks again man really appreciate you!